# Class templates and casting

Tags: c++, oop

So I'm trying to write a copy constructor for class E such that it will get every int x from each class and assign it to its counterpart. How do I cast the right side?

```
class A
{
public:
    int x;
};

class B: public virtual A
{
public:
    int x;
};

class C: public virtual A
{
public:
    int x;
};

class D : public B, public C
{
public:
    int x;
};

class E: public D
{
public:
    int x;

    E(const E& e)
    {
        E::x = (E)e.x // problem
        D::x = ?
        C::x = ?
        B::x = ?
        A::x = ?
    }
};
```

Comment: No templates present. Also, why would an `int` cast to an instance of `E`?

Comment: because I want to copy E's x into the x of the current instance of E, same for D and C, and so in the hierarchy. And there are no templates, somebody changed the title...

Comment: There is no reason to cast this int.

Comment: if I just leave it like 'x = e.x' it copies A's x from A's x. What about B,C,D and E's x?

Comment: Please update your question to actually reflect what your problem is. Please also include a runnable example illustrating the problem.

Comment: The easiest solution is to remove the copy constructor entirely. The implicitly defined one will do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to cast an int to assign it to an int. Just do:

```
self->x = ((E)e).x;
D::x = ((D)e).x;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
E::x = e.E::x;
D::x = e.D::x;
C::x = e.C::x;
B::x = e.B::x;
A::x = e.A::x;
```

Though it might be wiser to give each class a suitable copy constructor, with a suitable initialization list invoking copy constructors of base classes.